# How is int Prec value decided in Calcite's SqlBinaryOperator?

Tags: apache-calcite

SqlBinaryOperator constructor Takes Prec value as input to add support for an operator. I wanted to know how that value is decided?
Thank you

Looking at SqlstdOperatorTable, I saw the values for existing Prec values of various operators but couldn't figure out the logic myself